# Doxygen C# XML comments and generics do not generate links in HTML output

Tags: c#, documentation, doxygen, xml-comments

I could not find anything about on the net and i´m quite clueless to the XML comment support in doxygen.

My problem is as simple as this:

```
/// <see cref="GenericClass{TTypeparam}"/>
```

Which seems to me to be the correct way to reference an open generic in XML comments, does not produce a link in the doxygen output. It just copies the text from the cref attribute to the output.

I know that linking to generics works in doxygen from custom pages by using `GenericClass<TTypeParam>`. So is this a known bug, or did i miss something obvious?

Btw. I´m using doxygen 1.8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doxygen does not support the { .. } syntax inside cref at the moment. You could regard this as a bug. Feel free to submit a bug report in doxygen's bug tracker for this.

Comment: Is there a conceptual problem or is it simply a missing feature?

Comment: It is a missing feature. It should already work if you use \ref instead of the XML equivalent.

Comment: Thx. We use the xml version because of navigation support in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Doxygen just doesn't seem to have a good way to handle generics at the moment (in 1.8.8) - unless you're happy to forget the standard Microsoft-supported XML format (which uses {...} syntax) and switch to using "GenericClass" or "\ref GenericClass" (both of which are of course invalid XML that the Visual Studio tooling won't like).

See doxygen bugs https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=738173, https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=738167 and https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=704090